# how to combine two statement together

Tags: erlang

I want to combine the following two subclauses together (contain repeated statements), but don't know how to write? How to express "not nil"?

```
handle_call({unset_file_output},State=#single_process_log_state{file_description=nil}) ->
    State1 = State#single_process_log_state
    {
      is_need_file_log=false
    },
   {ok,ok,State1};
handle_call({unset_file_output},State=#single_process_log_state{
                  file_description=File_description}) ->
    file:close(File_description),       
    State1 = State#single_process_log_state
    {
      is_need_file_log=false
    },
    {ok,ok,State1};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following function:

```
close_file(nil) -> ok;
close_file(FD)  -> ok = file:close(FD).
```